# Android architecture

Tags: android

Now I am doing an android project(Api level 8),I install JD-Eclipse(decompiler) to know the flow of program execution.The decompiled 'android.jar' contains full of abstract classes and interfaces, then where is the actual class containing the body to be executed? What is the name of that jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android.jar contains the Android API (Classes, interfaces, ..). If you want to see the rest, download the source from [Android Git repository](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) or via SDK Manager.

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't find what you are looking for. The `android.jar` is an API and as that not directly executable, there isn't even any guarantee that it contains such code.

If you want to start creating an application, just go to the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) and start reading through the documentation on how to set up the development environment, how to program against the API, how to test your application and, finally, how to deploy it on an actual device.

The lifecycle of an activity for example can be found [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).